# Move excel files from a source to different folders- Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of excel files named apple.xlsx, mango.xlsx etc. These all are in "C:\Users\Public\Fruits\". I stored all fruits name in fruits.xlsx. I am a newbie in Excel-VBA. May I know how to move these files to folders Apple, Mango upto 500 folders for 500 different fruits ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Name Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264639.aspx) to change the name and location of files.

For example:

```
Name "C:\Example_Folder_1\apple.xlsx" As "C:\Example_Folder_2\apple.xlsx"
```

This will move the file to `Example_Folder_2` from `Example_Folder_1`.

You can combine this with a loop if you already have the names of all your files. For example, if the list of fruits were in the range `A2:A500` like this:

```
 |  A
1|Fruits
2|Apple
3|Mango
4|Pear
5|Banana
```

You could do this:

```
Sub MoveFiles()

Dim flName as String, OldFldr as String, NewFldr as String
Dim Cell as Range

'Set old folder name
OldFldr = "C:\Users\Public\Fruits\"

'Loop through fruits
For each Cell in Thisworkbook.Sheets("Fruits").Range("A2:A500")

    'Set new folder name
    NewFldr = OldFldr & Cell.Value

    'Check whether new fruit specific folder already exists and if not, create it
    If Dir(NewFldr , vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (NewFldr & "\")
    End If

    'Set filename
    flName = Cell.Value & ".xlsx"

    'Move file to new folder
    Name Oldfldr & flName As NewFldr & "\" & flName

Next Cell

End Sub
```

This will put your fruit specific files into fruit specific folders.